# Write logic gates from logic gate circuit

Tags: math, logic, circuit

Could someone please show me how to write the logic from this logic circuit?

[image]

Following you guys' explanation, I have these results, am I right:

[image]

The question is which one of a, b, c, d produces the same ouput as the first circuit. I don't see any similar results here, please illuminate me !

Comment: Remember that input to the n-th gate is the output from the (n-1)-th gates. Since you already know how to compute the expression for simple circuits, this should get you started.

Comment: @shree.pat18 hi, thanks for your comment, can you check my edited question to see if i have done anything wrong please ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about circuit design. Ask on [electronics.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give names to the intermediate terms, e.g. S and T, where S is the output of the AND gate and T is the output of the inverter (NOT gate), then you can break it down as follows:

```
X = S | T                ; final OR gate
S = A & B                ; output of AND gate
T = ~B                   ; output of inverter (NOT gate)
X = (A & B) | ~B         ; substitute above
```

Note that this is a poor example as the expression can be reduced to:

```
X = ~(~A & B)
```

which can be implemented with just two gates (a NAND and a NOT), or

```
X = A | ~B
```

which can also be implemented with two gates (an OR and a NOT).

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the answer, i have updated my question, please take a look !

Comment: One question per question please, and you shouldn't really change a question once it has an accepted answer. But I agree: none of them are correct, but (d) is close - it's correct if you switch the A and B inputs.

Comment: oh im sorry, i'm new here. I tried to post another question but it says i have to wait for 90 minutes, but i'm leaving my school in 1 hour, means won't be able to post the question until tomorrow morning, and i have to do the homework to night :(

Comment: No problem - leave it as it is now - I've edited my comment so you may need to refresh the page in your browser.

Comment: My bad - (b) is correct - see my updated answer above (the last part).

Comment: Thanks very much, but i don't understand how come (A&B) | ~B = ~(~A&B) ?

Comment: You need to use [de Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Also writing out a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) can help a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Start from the inputs:

The **AND** gate gets **A** and **B** as inputs, and the **NOT** gate gets **B** as its input. The outputs of these 2 are the inputs to the **OR** Gate.

Therefore let 
**Y = A AND B**
and **Z = (NOT B)**

=> **X = Y OR Z**

=> **X = (A AND B) OR (NOT B)**

**UPDATE**

I think **b** is the right answer.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the answer, i have updated my question, please take a look !

Comment: If it helps see this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+AND+B%29+OR+%28NOT+B%29

Comment: oh this's so so helpful, thanks so much, i understand totally now, thanks a lot !!!!! i wish i could mark yours as answer !!